# Bootstrap 4: Responsive layouts that depend on aspect ratios

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to implement the following responsive layout within Bootstrap 4:

- I have a row with two equal sized columns
- I want the columns to be side by side when the device's aspect ratio (width / height) is greater than 1 (i.e. landscape) AND the height is less than 992px
- I want the columns to be stacked in all other cases (i.e. portrait or "landscape with sufficient height")

In other "words":

```
if w/h > 1 and h < 992:
    # side by side
else
    # stacked
```

How do I do this with Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to the columns, then change the width based on window height, probably easiest with jQuery

```
<div class="col-md-6 special-class">something</div>
<div class="col-md-6 special-class">something else</div>

<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
  checkSize()
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  checkSize()
})

function checkSize() {
  var aspect = $(window).width() / $(window).height()
  if($(window).height() < 992  && aspect > 1) {
    $('.special-class').css({'flex': '0 0 50%', 'max-width': '50%'})
  } else {
    $('.special-class').css({'flex': '0 0 100%', 'max-width': '100%'})
  }
}
</script>
```

Downside here is the resize event is expensive, check into throttling it with underscore or lodash.

Basic fiddle, doesn't do the aspect bit: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/42225/